# How to work with node.js and mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I read :

- [How do I manage MongoDB connections in a Node.js web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-to-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-nodejs-webapp-)
- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html
- [How can I set up MongoDB on a Node.js server using node-mongodb-native in an EC2 environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789045/how-can-i-set-up-mongodb-on-a-node-js-server-using-node-mongodb-native-in-an-ec2?lq=1)

And I am really confused. How I should work with mongoDB from node.js? I’m a rookie, and my question may look stupid.

```
var db = new db.MongoClient(new db.Server('localhost', 27017));
    db.open(function(err, dataBase) {
       //all code here?
       dataBase.close();
    });
```

Or every time when I needing something from db I need call:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB", function(err, dataBase) {
    //all code here 
    dataBase.close();
});
```

What is the difference betwen open and connect? I read in the manual that open: Initialize and second connect. But what exactly does that mean?  I assume that both do the same, but in the other way, so when should I use one instead the other?

I also wanna ask it's normal that mongoClient needing 4 socket? I running two myWEbServer at the same time, here’s picture:
http://i43.tinypic.com/29mlr14.png

EDIT:
I wanna mention that this isn't a problem ( rather doubt :D), my server works perfect. I ask because I wanna know if I am using mongoDB driver correctly.
Now/Actually I use first option,init mongo dirver at the beginning and inside load put all code.

Comment: The 4 is connection pooling

Comment: Is it not possible to use Mongoose? http://mongoosejs.com/ Much simpler in my opinion.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#introduction?

Comment: @ Sammaye – I got it, thanks. 
@Tony – I knew that, someone will suggest some library.I read about it, I can use it, but I won't. Mongoose make it simpler, faster, better… maybe. But I don't need it as soon as possible. I write it to myself. Also I don't like abstraction layer. I study so I wanna two thing: simple and basic ( using core funtion which provide driver) code which I understand. It may sound stupid for you(everyone), if so just ignore my question.

Comment: you can find a nodejs and mongodb tutorial.  https://programmerblog.net/nodejs-mongodb-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend trying the [MongoDB tutorial](http://try.mongodb.org/) they offer. I was in the same boat, but this breaks it down nicely. In addition, there's [this article](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html) on github that explains the basics of DB connection.

In short, it does look like you're doing it right.

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB", function(err, dataBase) {
    //all code here 
    var collection = dataBase.collection('users');
    var document1 = {'name':'John Doe'};
    collection.insert(document1, {w:1}, function(err,result){
        console.log(err);
    });
    dataBase.close();
});
```

Comment: I read this. I know how to work with mongoDB, from main tutorial. For every drivers querying rule are the same. What you suggest is wrong, look: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html
I wrote above guessing about difference between open and connect method. Why you have two functions doing exactly the same? This would not be a problem if someone write next to one ‘deprecated’

Answer (score 1):

You still can sign up for a free course [M101JS: MongoDB for Node.js Developers](https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101JS/2013_August/about), provided by MongoDB guys

Here is short description:

> This course will go over basic installation, JSON, schema design,
>   querying, insertion of data, indexing and working with language
>   drivers. In the course, you will build a blogging platform, backed by
>   MongoDB. Our code examples will be in Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

I had same question. I couldn't find any proper answer from mongo documentation. 
All document say is to prefer new db connection and then use open (rather than using connect() )
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/connect/