# How to forward request to Node.js from nginx with tcp_proxy_module?

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

Now, I had patched [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) with the `nginx_tcp_proxy_module`, and it is running OK on port 8080.

How do I connect the clients to port 80 of nignx, not port 8080 of [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs), 
so that having the nginx forward the request to Node.js?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx + (nodejs, socketio, express) + php site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685924/nginx-nodejs-socketio-express-php-site)

Answer (score 2):

Just change 8080 to 80. But TCP and HTTP on the same port [is not possible](https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module/issues/6).

## Aleternative solution:

- Use HAProxy on port 80
- Set up nginx to listen on port 81
- Run your node.js app on port 8080
- Configure [HAProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360221/haproxy-websocket-disconnection/4737648#4737648) to

  - forward `Host: your.nodejs.socketio.com` to 127.0.0.1:8080
  - forward everything else to 127.0.0.1:81

If you go down this route you will probably want to preserve client IPs:

- Configure [HAproxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/30311/remote-ips-with-haproxy)
- Use [RealIP module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealIpModule) in nginx
- Use X-Forwarded-For in socket.io

  ```
  socketio.handshakeData = function(data) {
      var d = socketio.Manager.prototype.handshakeData(data);
      d.ip = data.request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || data.request.connection.remoteAddress;
      return d;
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks, now haproxy had successfully forwarded http request to nginx and websocket requests to nodejs(only in chrome), but fail to forward xhr-polling and jsonp-polling requests( ie and firefox)

Comment: Remove `acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket`