# Use Socket.io and Node.js on existing page (with nginx)?

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm trying to expand an existing Webpage (NGINX + PHP5 + MySQL) with a real time API that feeds some additional data (for example, an in-page chat).

After going trough some standalone testscripts, etc, I'm actually already having troubles just to set up a simple chat example: Socket.io doesnt want to work, apparently because of dependencies.

I'm trying to use NodeJS/Socket.io **only** as alternative to fdajax - I never intended to build my whole (already existing) page on nodejs. So, my main question is, how can I 'implement' those two libraries, and still make them work (even if `socket.io.js` isnt delivered by `nodejs`)

My current error is `ReferenceError: require is not defined` and `ReferenceError: io is not defined` when including `socket.io.js`. Apparently, the reason is that the function `require()` probably doesnt work properly, since - well, nodejs isnt delivering the whole page, but PHP does (so, I guess, the whole require() stuff is missing).

**Does someone know how I can get `socket.io` to work, whitout having nodejs deliver the whole page, but instead still using the already existing NGINX+PHP setup?**

I tried a couple of things, but couldnt find a good hint yet. The target basically is, to just include `socket.io.js` (and other required stuff), connect to the nodejs webserver over the specified port (8080, or whatever), and then write some code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could try having PHP ping nodejs in case there is update required and still have business-logic in PHP (so socket.io and the rest is just a delivery mechanism). Or try researching http://socketo.me

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a full fledged example from another answer/question** https://stackoverflow.com/a/14709236/1489655

---

You can setup a proxy for the websocket traffic.

```
tcp {
    upstream websockets {
        ## node processes
        server 127.0.0.1:8001;
        server 127.0.0.1:8002;
        server 127.0.0.1:8003;
        server 127.0.0.1:8004; 

        check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
    }   

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        server_name _;

        tcp_nodelay on;
        proxy_pass websockets;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets

This should allow you to connect to socket.io via

```
var socket = new io.Socket('ws://localhost');
```