# How to access event machine websockets through Thin/nginx?

Tags: ruby, nginx, websocket, eventmachine, thin

I have an event-machine websocket application (using the [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket) gem) and it runs fine. The problem is that I need to deploy it using port 80 through nginx (can't compile it with tcp proxy module). Is it possible to use a simple nginx proxy_pass pointing to a thin server and have the thin server to pass the requests to my websocket server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you can't proxy websocket traffic with a proxy_pass.

> Since web sockets are done over HTTP 1.1 connections (where the handshake and upgrade are completed), your backend needs to support HTTP 1.1, and from what I have researched, they break the HTTP 1.0 spec...

I've seen some people try to do the same thing with socket.io and HAProxy (see links). I would guess that you could try to swap out the socket.io with em-websockets and expect similar results.

1: http://www.letseehere.com/reverse-proxy-web-sockets

2: [HAProxy + WebSocket Disconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360221/haproxy-websocket-disconnection/4737648#4737648)