# Socket.io, HAProxy over port 80 not working with Trend Micro

Tags: websocket, socket.io, haproxy

HAProxy listens on port 80, and is configured like [HAProxy + WebSocket Disconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360221/haproxy-websocket-disconnection/4737648#4737648)

Socket.io listens on a private port.

For the vast majority of people, this works fine. They connect over port 80, and everything is great.

However, some people have Trend Micro "Worry Free Business Security" installed, and this is breaking websocket connections using socket.io. If I force it to use xhr-polling, it works fine.

Engine.io works fine for people with Trend, so it's something with how socket.io realises that the websocket connection is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried on ssl version yet? (port 443) I once have a problem with port 80 too. Force user to use 443 can reduce some people who cannot access your app.

Comment: I haven't tried SSL yet on it, but there is now some logic in the client side to use a higher port (above 1000) if port 80 fails.

As you have been the only one to answer, I'll mark yours as the accepted answer and award the bounty.

Comment: Please put in mind that socket.io will not work in some company that has a firewall that restrict to port 80 and 443 (standard port). It's up to your customer if there's a customer who use your system from behind a firewall or not. You can use haproxy to sort that problem out if you cannot use port 80, 443.