# Socket.io connection failing when passing through Nginx

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My app works fine when i connect to it directly but when i proxy through Nginx i get an "unexpected continuation frame" error in the browser. How can I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [special configuration for websockets](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) described on nginx website. You may want to try either of them to see which one works best for you (if works at all).

But as [noted in Socket.IO wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Nginx-and-Socket.io), it's best to use [HAProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360221/haproxy-websocket-disconnection/4737648#4737648) or Varnish.